# Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 8 (Offline)

Tags: indexeddb, offline-caching

I have a web page that is suppose to be able to work offline and it does perfectly when I am on localhost and have no internet connection. When i hosted my page on my server and ran it off line (disconnecting the internet) it throws me an error.

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 8 
request.onsuccess
```

I don't know why it doing this. It works fine when I have internet connection. I tested in firefox and ie10 online and offline and it fine. It does not break the code either, everything still works fine, it just throw me the error and does not get the data for me to render when I refresh/load the page.Here's where it is complaining.

```
 var version = 1;
 var request = window.indexedDB.open(webDB.currentProperty, version);
 request.addEventListener('blocked', function () { console.log('blocked'); });
 console.log(webDB.currentProperty);
 request.onsuccess = function (event) {
    webDB.database = request.result;
    // make transactiona reference to the database with read option (read is the   
    default option when none is provided)       
    var transaction = webDB.database.transaction([webDB.currentProperty]);
    // hide or show elements after data has been populated 
    transaction.oncomplete = function () {
        console.log("complete");
    };
    //Get the objectstore (conatains all the object) to do things
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(webDB.currentProperty);
```

I check my chrome version it's 28 and I checked to see if I was getting block when I open the database but I'm not.

**EDIT**

When I explicitly give it a read-only option

```
var transaction = webDB.database.transaction([webDB.currentProperty], "read-only");
```

it throws a type error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error
request.onsuccess
```

Answer (score 0):

- read-only is not one of the proper typesn for starting a tx. there are 3 types, see the mozilla docs for info.
- i would try hardcoding the db name in your call to indexedDB.open as something funky may be happening to your webDB.currentProperty variable somewhere else. debug this first.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) it says that it is read-only, readwrite, and version change. I know that it webDB.currentProperty works becuase I check that it only contains alphnumeric characters. Also like I said above it works perfectly fine while I have internet connection but once I take it of line it then throws me the error. Yet it still works and after doing stuff on the page and refreshing it it goes away.